# Get last part of string

Tags: php, arrays

I have dynamic list of names, for example:

```
 1) John Cena
 2) Nepresso USA Inc.
 3) Adam & Christie Rana
```

I need to fectch  first and last name here, in this case I need result like:

```
 1) $array[0]=John , $array[1]=Cena
 2) $array[0]=Nepresso , $array[1]=USA Inc.
 3) $array[0]=Adam , $array[1]=& Christie Rana
```

Basically first string before first space would be on 0th index of array.
 Although I have  a way to `explode` it by "Space" and `Implode` the string again start from 1st index upto end of exploded array.
 I am looking for an efficient way to get 1st index which have rest of part of string.

Comment: Just use strpos : http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php

Comment: In your list, does the numering exists `1), 2), 3) ...` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `explode()` function is an efficient way.

Just use its 3rd parameter which says how many of substrings you want to get.

Use

```
$array = explode(' ',$string,2);
```

to get two substrings.